# O que é o Lombok?

Tags: java, framework, biblioteca

O que é o `Lombok` e como eu poderia usá lo em uma classe java?
Quais as vantagens  e desvantagens de seu manuseio em uma aplicação java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `Lombok` é um `Framework` criado sob licença `MIT`, podendo ser usado livremente em qualquer projeto Java. Seu principal objetivo é diminuir a verbosidade das classes de mapeamento `JPA, DTOs e Beans` por exemplo.

Sua vantagem é evitar a repetição de código "clichê", como a criação de gets e sets para todos os atributos, métodos `equals e hashCode, toString, Construtores` entre outros. Dessa forma, o código fica mais limpo e claro.

Uma desvantagem que senti é a necessidade de instalação de `Plugin no Intellij e Eclipse`. Acredito que esses são as `IDEs` atualmente suportadas apenas.

Recomendo a utilização.

Fontes:

- [https://projectlombok.org](https://projectlombok.org/)
- [http://blog.caelum.com.br/java-menos-verboso-com-lombok/](http://blog.caelum.com.br/java-menos-verboso-com-lombok)

Comment: Funciona normalmente no NetBeans também, inclusive **sem** a necessidade de instalar qualquer *plugin*.