# Como transformar os atributos em propriedades?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, propriedade, getters-setters

No C#, eu consigo evitar o uso de `getter` e `setter`, transformando os atributos em propriedades, conforme abaixo:

```
public class Pessoa {
    public int pes_idade { get; set; }
    public string pes_nome { get; set; }
}
```

Tem como fazer isto em Java?

Comment: Existe o [Lombok](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok) que substitui o getter e o setter por annotation.

Comment: Este aqui e o [site oficial](https://projectlombok.org/) do Lombok.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Se ainda não o fez, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 6):

Em C# você cria propriedade que nada mais é que um campo privado (e não, [atributo que é outra coisa em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75265/101)) com um par de métodos (pode ser um só) que vão dar acesso a este campo. Você não os vê como métodos (é açúcar sintático) mas é o que ele é. Seria basicamente isso:

```
public class Pessoa {
    private int idade;
    public int getIdade() { return idade; }
    public void setIdade(int value) { idade = value; }
    private String nome;
    public String getNome() { return nome; }
    public void setNome(String value) { nome = value; }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/GetterSetter.java).

Em Java não tem essa facilidade, então tem que fazer na mão, exatamente desta forma. A não ser que use o [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) (vide comentários). Não vejo muito as pessoas fazendo, deve haver um motivo (pode ser só desconhecimento, mas parece que não é só isso). Veja [O que é o Lombok?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141294/101)

## Funcionamento desse padrão

Isso cria uma indireção que é útil para versionamento e carregamento dinâmico de módulos, porque a lógica do acesso passa para o método, então sempre que você atualizar o método na classe, todo mundo que chamá-lo receberá a nova execução, mesmo que nada que faça o acesso tenha sido recompilado (só o componente da classe mudada é que foi recompilada).

Se usasse o campo direto isso não seria possível porque o acesso é feito de forma direta. Uma mudança nessa classe exigira a recompilação de toda a aplicação para garantir que o acesso fosse feito de acordo com o novo funcionamento.

Então em alguns casos usar o campo não é um problema, mesmo que no futuro precise mudar para um método que tenha um processamento. Mas se não tem certeza que uma mudança poderá afetar toda a aplicação, então é melhor se garantir já colocando um método que faz uma operação bem básica, que é a propriedade em C#, ou o padrão de *getter* e *setter* no Java.

[Não sou fã do termo atributo, prefiro campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Comment: É possivel um programador implementar essa "facilidade" no java usando que ele tem hoje, ou o esforço para isso não vale a pena, tendo em vista que é mais um "efeito visual" no código?

Comment: Não. O que dá para fazer é criar alguma coisa no IDE (alguns já tem algo) que facilite você digitar o campo e ele criar os métodos para você. Mas os métodos ficarão visíveis no seu código, correm o risco de serem modificados, etc.

Comment: https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html

Comment: @diegofm olha aí, o Gabriel mostrou que tem uma ferramenta que ajuda nisso. Não sei como ela funciona mas ou precisa de um ferramenta externa que faz uma pré-compilação, ou faz uma injeção de código ou tem um custo de *runtime* para lidar com isso.

Comment: @bigown Na verdade o lombok meio que *sequestra* o compilador para fazer o seu trabalho. Não tenho certeza, mas se não me engano, no javac, ele usa truques de `ClassLoader`s para carregar versões modificadas das classes internas do javac, alterando o comportamento do compilador. No ecj, ele usa um agente para instrumentar as classes do compilador por meio do `preMain`, e então também alterar o funcionamento do compilador.

Answer (score -1):

No Java é assim:

```
public class Pessoa {

    private String nome;
    private int idade;


    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }

}
```

Comment: A pergunta do AP é sobre uma funcionalidade q permita usar os atributos da classe como propriedades, os gettes e setters servem para encapsular os atributos.

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu(ou não leu) a pergunta. Ele quer saber se tem como escrever getters e setters semelhante(a sintaxe) ao c#

Comment: Atenta-te a pergunta, caro.